# Nested CSS in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs

I've been working on a react project and I most of the time used Sass as a CSS preprocessor as it has nesting options, but now CSS has added nesting on its own, So I tried to add in the react project and it doesn't seems to be working.

#### [CSS Nesting ↗](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/)

#### Pure HTML and CSS

> The below code is working while using pure html and css.
>
> ```css
> .selection {
>   background-color: blue;
>   color: white;
>   
>   & #gender {
>     border: 2px solid red;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <div class="selection">
>   <label htmlFor="gender">Gender: </label>
>   <select name="gender" id="gender">
>     <option value="">Select Gender</option>
>     <option value="male">Male</option>
>     <option value="female">Female</option>
>     <option value="other">Other</option>
>   </select>
> </div>
> ```

#### ReactJS JSX code with CSS module in NextJS

> Below code is not working.

```js
import styles from "./form.module.css"

export default function Gender() {
  return(
    <div className={styles.selection}>
      <label htmlFor="gender">Gender: </label>
      <select name="gender" id="gender">
        <option value="">Select Gender</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```css
.selection {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;

  & #gender {
    border: 2px solid red;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at what the rendered CSS looks like?  My hunch would be this is a build process preprocessor issue— do you have any error messaging there?